# SIGSEGV with indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, mov

i have a problem with a piece of assembly code embedded in a c program.

```
jmp    0x8048408 <main+44>
0x080483e4 <+8>:    pop    %esi
0x080483e5 <+9>:    xor    %eax,%eax
=> 0x080483e7 <+11>:    mov    %ah,0x7(%esi)
0x080483ea <+14>:   mov    $0xffffffff,%ebx
0x080483ef <+19>:   sub    $0xfffffffe,%ebx
0x080483f2 <+22>:   mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
0x080483f7 <+27>:   sub    $0xfffffffb,%eax
0x080483fa <+30>:   int    $0x80
0x080483fc <+32>:   xor    %ebx,%ebx
0x080483fe <+34>:   mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
0x08048403 <+39>:   sub    $0xfffffffe,%eax
0x08048406 <+42>:   int    $0x80
0x08048408 <+44>:   call   0x80483e4 <main+8>
```

The problem is the <+11> mov line: every time i use parenthesis on a register to get the memory location instead of the register itself, i get a SIGSEGV.
I'm starting to think that it's not fault of the code, do you have any idea?
Even if i try something like:   mov %eax, (%eax); i get the sigsegv error

plz help!

Comment: What platform/environment/setup are you running this on?

Comment: How do you know that the register contains a valid address?

Comment: I run on debian 64 bit, but i compiled it with -m32.
The address is correct, because the call instruction at the end put the address of the next line on the stack, and the next line is .string "something".
I checked with gdb and that's correct, the problem could be that the address is of a data area maybe, could it?

Comment: Here are the two last lines:
"call 0x80483e4;"
".string \"dddddddddddddddd\";"

The address in esi is the address of that string

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write to an address within your code segment, which in most sane environments will be read-only, hence the SIGSEGV.

Comment: mmm ok, but then, why this works (i'm following this tutorial)

http://pastebin.com/dX0nsjCw

Comment: Because in that case the string (which is passed as a function argument) is stored somewhere else (e.g. on the stack, or in the heap, or in a global data segment), where it is most likely writeable.